# How to reset a Default username and password of Allied Telesis AT9000/28 switch using CLI?

Tags: routing, switch, network, networking, switching-modes

How to reset a Default username and password of Allied Telesis AT9000/28 switch  using CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I would defy the purpose - securing management access - if you could reset the credentials via console.

As it seems, AT has made no provisions to reset the password by physical reset switch either. You should contact their support.

[EDIT] There seems to be a procedure using the serial console:

> 1. Connect to the router using a RS-232 cable
> 2. Connect to the router via HyperTerminal
> 3. Settings for HyperTerminal = 9600 - 8 - None - 1 Flow Control = None
> 4. Power cycle the router and right away press the s key continuously until you see the login prompt > (Starts up with current release but
>    no configuration)
> 5. You will now have to Delete the previous manager password configuration line described below using the internal text editor. The
>    editor is invoked with the command: EDIT filename.cfg (filename is the
>    name of you config file) Delete the line that states: set user=manager
>    pass=3af00c6cad11f7ab5db4467b66ce503eff priv=manager Save and exit
>    editor by pressing the key sequence of Ctrl k x
> 6. Now, type the command >restart router to reload the original configuration. The Manager password is now regenerated as "friend"

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=46654

Comment: is there is no any solution to solve this .... via console ?